# Django Performance, url.py evaluation and cache

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, optimization, django-queryset

I have developed project with django. Now facing few problem with optimizations. I have created/used around 53 small applications. Each applications have their local url.py file with their defined urls.

Now there is a main project url.py. this url.py file define urls and include every application local url.py.

Now Each time when user hit any url, Main url.py file is called, which itself call each of the every single url.py then return view for user to hit.

My Question is very simple that how we can force urls.py to be loaded at once and serve urls directly from cache without evaluating every single url.py on every user hit?

```
Test configurations:
Django 1.5
python 2.7
Server django test server "runserver"

Deployment Configuration:
Django 1.5
python 2.7
Server apache22 with modwisgi
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how django processes the HttpRequest https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request

the first 3 steps are:

> 1. Django determines the root URLconf module to use. Ordinarily, this
>      is the value of the ROOT_URLCONF setting, but if the incoming
>      HttpRequest object has an attribute called urlconf (set by
>      middleware request processing), its value will be used in place of
>      the ROOT_URLCONF setting.
> 2. Django loads that Python module and looks for the variable
>          urlpatterns. This should be a Python list of django.conf.urls.url()
>          instances.
> 3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the
>      first one that matches the requested URL.

for your purpose you would need to write your own middleware between 2 and 3 which first looks for a pattern in cache, if it doesnot find, it should go on with step 3.

But I dont think you need this. I would go for caching views which is much heavier than urls.

Comment: Since my website is dynamic content, content is filtered with logedin user. also each individual application have it's own url.py(urls are dynamic but same everytime like CRUD urls for each registered models) which are imported in main url.py